# Catalyst $c->request->upload('field') returns empty string

Tags: perl, file-upload, catalyst

I'm trying to access upload file input from a Catalyst controller using '$c->request->upload'. But for some reason it keeps returning an empty string.

This is my form:

```
<form id="import_test" action="/tests/import_tests" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
    <input type="file" name="testFile" class="fileInput" />
</form>
```

From my controller subroutine,

```
my $upload = $c->req->upload('testFile');
warn $upload;
```

Please let me know if there is any other information required. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`$upload` is an object, specifically a [Catalyst::Request::Upload](https://metacpan.org/module/MRAMBERG/Catalyst-Runtime-5.7002/lib/Catalyst/Request/Upload.pm) object. Your warning is probably returning a memory address like `HASH (0x0AB85C2790E4480C)`.

As a first pass, try `warn ref $upload;` to assert this.

Assuming that returns `Catalyst::Request::Upload`, try:

```
warn $upload->filename ;
```